# Legend disappears when printing to PDF using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I have a figure made in the print composer, but when I "Export as pdf, both the legend and our company logo disappear.

Any idea why?

I have not had this problem before. 
Using QGIS 2.18.10

Comment: Do you the same problem when you export the layout as image?

Comment: No, I do not have that problem when I export it an an image.

Comment: Do you use the "export as raster" option?

Comment: @underdak, as ahmadhanb suggested, exporting as an image works, and I can then pdf it. I could not figure out how to "export as raster" from the composer window but I have the pdf so that is all I need thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your project? It would be important to check if this isn't a bug worth fixing.

Answer (score 1):

To translate my comment as an answer:

You can export the layout as image instead of PDF, then in any image processing software you can open the image file and save it as PDF.

I am not sure if this is a bug or not in QGIS 2.18.10, but at least I did not face the same problem in the QGIS 2.14.19 LTR version.